# openshift .netcore 1.1 build error

Tags: json, openshift, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-1.1

I am trying to build a sample webapi project using VS-2017 community  in openshift with .netcore 1.1 template but its an building error.

> Cloning "https://github.com/kuntal-b/netcoreWebAPI" ...
>     Commit: 84b604df745890311a7d23451c4bbef6552d1fb1 (2)
>     Author: kuntal.bose01@gmail.com    Date:   Thu
>   May 25 23:11:27 2017 +0530 Pulling image
>   "registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7@sha256:7c775cc11b280105f51bf2622ed79036c7f961e1cb9db23c4b17c66606154f7b"
>   ... Pulling image
>   "registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7@sha256:7c775cc11b280105f51bf2622ed79036c7f961e1cb9db23c4b17c66606154f7b"
>   ...
>   ---> Copying application source ...
>   ---> Installing dependencies ... warn : The folder '/opt/app-root/src' does not contain a project to restore.
>   ---> Building application ... Couldn't find 'project.json' in '.' error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from
>   registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7@sha256:7c775cc11b280105f51bf2622ed79036c7f961e1cb9db23c4b17c66606154f7b

**Building application ... Couldn't find 'project.json' in '.' error:**
.net core 1.1 template don't have a project.json file.

Comment: In case it helps, there was a series of blog posts about using dotNet with OpenShift at https://blog.openshift.com/category/technologies/dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

Using s2i with dotnetcore will only work in openshift with the old project.json based projects. This will be fixed once .net standard 2.0 is released.

Check: https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/issues/46

Comment: Support for dotnetcore 2.0 has been released: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/08/22/red-hat-releases-net-core-2-0/

Hope it helps!